# Piping output to a text file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a method here, although I would like to pipe the output from it to a file e.g. output.txt, how could I do this in this context?

```
  foreach (string tmpLine in File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\filename.txt"))
  {
    if (File.Exists(tmpLine))
    {
      //output
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's it:

```
var file = File.AppendText(@"c:\output.txt");

foreach (string tmpLine in File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\filename.txt"))
{
    if (File.Exists(tmpLine))
    {       
        file.WriteLine(tmpLine);
    }
}

file.Close();
```

Comment: Better, of course, would be to use a `using` block on `file`.

Answer (score 3):

Normally command line wise, you do

```
mycommand > somefile.txt
```

or

```
mycommand | more
```

This works because output is written to std out.

You could try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx